I'm having trouble with autofill suggestions for Context.sb. in SeleniumBase and Behave BDD code; no BaseCase suggestions appear
I’m not able to select a suggestion (send_keys) or any other option after I hit the dot for Context.sb. The suggestions that appear are not related to BaseCase, only what I have already used, like assert_title. Even though the code passed, I’m missing something here.
from behave import step

@step("I am on the homepage")
def open_homePage(Context):
       Context.sb.open("https://practice.sdetunicorns.com/")
@step("the page loads")
def assert_title(Context):
      Context.sb.assert_title("Practice E-Commerce Site – SDET Unicorns")
@step("I should see the logo")
def assert_title(Context):
         Context.sb.assert_element(".custom-logo-link")
@step("I should see the text")
def assert_title(Context):
        Context.sb.assert_text("Think different. Make different.","h1")``


Feature: Header # features/header.feature:2

  Scenario: Display header with logo  # features/header.feature:8
    Given I am on the homepage        # features/steps/headersteps.py:4 5.086s
    When the page loads               # features/steps/headersteps.py:7 0.083s
    Then I should see the logo        # features/steps/headersteps.py:10 0.014s
   ✅ Scenario Passed!

  Scenario: Display homepage with text  # features/header.feature:13
    Given I am on the homepage          # features/steps/headersteps.py:4 4.250s
    When the page loads                 # features/steps/headersteps.py:7 0.081s
    Then I should see the text          # features/steps/headersteps.py:13 0.022s
   ✅ Scenario Passed!

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
2 scenarios passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
6 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m9.536s

